In React, how do I make an element expand when it is displayed?
Please take a look at this sandbox:
https://playcode.io/1852293
Desired effect:

After clicking the button, the yellow box show up by expanding from left to right. It looks like a animation where its width grows from 0 to 100px.

The inner blue box doesn't get rendered until its parent yellow box is fully expanded (width = 100px).


I know that I can make the element always mounted, set its initial width to 0, and use transition to achieve this effect, but it causes some other issues, so I wonder if I can do it via conditional rendering.
Thanks in advance!

It is not necessary to keep the component mounted. The above can be achieved by using multiple state variables.
You want two more state variables:

To toggle the child component display
To start and end parent component animation (or transition)

Also,you can make use of this event: onTransitionEnd. This will be helpful in showing the child component only after transition is over.
The Main component looks like this:
export function App(props) {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [transition,setTransition] = useState(false);
  const [showChild,setShowChild] = useState(false);
  
  function handleClick() {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen)
    setShowChild(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(isOpen){
      setTransition(true);
    }
    else{
       setTransition(false);
    }
  },[isOpen]);

  return (
    <>
      {
        isOpen &&
        <div className={`parent ${transition ? 'slide' : 'noSlide'}`} onTransitionEnd={() => {
setShowChild(true);
        }}>
          {showChild && <div className='child'></div>}
        </div>
      }

      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me to display the div</button>
    </>
  );
}

And you can add this tiny CSS to get the desired effect:
.parent {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent.slide{
  width :100px;
  transition : width 1s ease-in;
}

Conditionally, the code adds a class slide and that class has the desired transition.
Here is a simple demo
